# Call method not defined in interface from implemented interface in Java

Tags: java, interface

I have the following scenario in Java. Let's say I have an interface, and two classes that implement this interface. As follows:

```
public interface myInterface {

    public String printStuff();

}

public class A implements myInterface {

    @Override
    public String printStuff(){
        return "Stuff";
    }
}


public class B implements myInterface {

    @Override
    public String printStuff(){
        return "Stuff";
    }

    public String printOtherStuff(){
        return "Other Stuff";
    }
}
```

How do I call the printOtherStuff method above if I define it as follows:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
 
     myInterface myinterface = new B();
     String str = myinterface.printOtherStuff(); // ? This does not work
}
```

The above calling code does not seem work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
myInterface myinterface = new B();
```

The reference type of `myinterface` is `myInterface`. That means you can only access the methods defined in the interface. You can cast it to type `B` in order to make the method call.

***NOTE***: From here on out I'll be using the proper naming conventions.

**Example**

```
MyInterface myInterface = new B();

String str = ((B)myInterface).printOtherStuff();
```

**Just a note on this**

If you need to do this, then you need to have a look at your class design. The idea of using an `interface` in this way is to abstract away from the details of the object's concrete implementation. If you're having to perform an explicit cast like this, then you might want to look into either changing your interface to accommodate the necessary methods, or change your class so that the method is moved into a global location (like a `util` file or something).

**Extra Reading**

You should read about reference types [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/reference-types-in-java.html), and you should have a look at casting [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting). My answer is a combination of the understanding of both of these things.

As an added note, take a look at the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). This is a vital piece of information for any Java developer to make understandable code.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative answer. Extra thanks for tips on naming conventions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely this wouldn't work because you have reference type of `Interface MyInterface`. At the time of **method binding** compiler would try to find this method in your `Interface MyInterface` which is not available. So you need to cast it to your class like this.

```
    MyInterface myInterface = new B();
    B newB=(B) myInterface ;//casting to class
    newB.printOtherStuff();// would work fine
```

Answer (score 0):

change `myInterface`

```java
public interface myInterface {

    public String printStuff();
    public String printOtherStuff();

}
```

If you cant change `myInterface`, then extends `myInterface`

```java
public interface myOtherInterface extends myInterface {

    public String printOtherStuff();

}
```

Then Implements `myOtherInterface`

```java
public class B implements myOtherInterface {

    @Override
    public String printStuff(){
        return "Stuff";
    }

    @Override
    public String printOtherStuff(){
        return "Other Stuff";
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
 
     myOtherInterface myotherinterface = new B();
     String str = myotherinterface.printOtherStuff(); 
}
```