# Why can't an interface type invoke a non-implemented public method of an object of the "subclass"?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

```java
public interface Interface {
    void interfaceMethod();
}

public class Subclass implements Interface{
    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod() {
        System.out.println("interface method");
    }
    public void subclassMethod(){
        System.out.println("subclass method");
    }
}

public class RunSubclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface obj = new Subclass();
        obj.interfaceMethod(); // works alone
        obj.subclassMethod(); // compilation error
    }
}
```

`obj` stores the reference to an object of Subclass, then why is it unable to invoke the public method `subclassMethod` too using that reference?

Comment: If you declare a variable as `TypeA myVar` then you will only ever be able to call the methods of `TypeA` on that variable because those are the only ones guaranteed to be available at all time. It doesn't matter whether TypeA is a Class or Interface.

Comment: Because `obj` is of type `Interface` and you only have access to the methods declared there.

Comment: You can only implement methods from `Interface` on a reference of type `Interface`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call method not defined in interface from implemented interface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135843/call-method-not-defined-in-interface-from-implemented-interface-in-java)